# How can I install drivers for an Intel 82915G/GV/910GL?

Tags: installation, drivers, intel

I installed Ubuntu to try it in my computer and I'm in love with it, but it doesn´t recognize my Intel 82915G/GV/910GL Express Chipset Family Integrated, I need help to do this, because I'm new to this OS.

I tried to find drivers using *Additional Drivers*, and

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

This tells me I already have the lastest version.

Can somebody help me to install this driver?

Comment: have You chcked on the Intel website if there are binary drivers for linux?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "doesnt recognise"... what isnt recognised?  please add the output of `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` to your question.

Answer (score 3):

The Intel driver is already installed by default in Ubuntu; I have the same chipset and, at the moment, I can't run Unity 3D with it. I just can run flawlessly Unity 2D, choosing it at the login screen.
If you want hardware acceleration, you could possibily try to add [Xord Edgers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=oneiric), but it's risky cause you could mess up your computer and I don't advice it, also because I don't know if with the updated driver you can succeed in using hardware acceleration and runnning Unity 3D.